# Question regarding set notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, set-theory

In an academic research paper in computer science,  I have a formula using the set builder notation in order to define a set $A$, as follows:

$$A = \{ y(b_i)=a_i | b_i \in B \}.$$

In the particular example, I want to convey in a concise way that each element $a_i \in A$ results from the transformation given by the function $y(b_i)$ for all $b_i \in B$.

1. Is that an appropriate and correct formulation, especially the part on the left-hand side (LHS) of the set builder?
2. That is, in set theory, is it allowed/correct to use an equality on the LHS of the set builder in the same way as above?

Comment: The answer to (a) and (b) is no. The correct formulation is $A=\{y(b)\mid b\in B\}$, or simply $A=y(B)$ ([direct image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Image_(mathematics)#Image_of_a_subset)). No $=a_i$ or $a_i=$ or $=a$ or $a=$ is correct, be it on the LHS or RHS of $\mid$, except if you write $$A=\{a\mid\exists b\in B,\;a=y(b)\}.$$

Comment: @AnneBauval I disagree---there is nothing wrong with the equality in the notation---it establishes a naming convention for future use.  I don't see a problem with writing something like $$ f = \{ y = f(x) : x \in \operatorname{dom}(f) \}. $$  It parses, and is perfectly readable, and helps to establish that the variable $y$ will generally be understood to represent something in the codomain of $f$.  The answer to the questions is largely a matter of *taste*.

Comment: @XanderHenderson I know you disagree (the second half of my comment was exactly a reaction to the two propositions in your answer below), and I agree to disagree. Being understandable or pleasant is $\ne$ from being correct.

Comment: @E-O For more explanations and examples, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-builder_notation#More_complex_expressions_on_the_left_side_of_the_notation

Comment: @AnneBauval But what is "correct" is *highly* context dependent.  If it is for your own notes or in the course notes for a lecture or seminar, the *only* thing that matters is clarity of communication.  If it is for a paper, it is correct as long as the reviewers and editors say that it is correct.  There is no objective standard for what is "correct" for all time and space, hence I am hesitant to give a universal "No" as an answer.

Comment: I find that it is generally best *not* be overly dogmatic about these kinds of things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notation you have suggested parses, and would likely be understood by most readers.  However, a couple of things would make it more clear:

1. You are defining an object $a_i$, which is an element of $A$.  It is easier to read from left-to-right, so I would suggest writing $a_i = y(b_i)$ (instead of $y(b_i) = a_i$).
2. The index $i$ is doing nothing for you in this notation.  I would drop it, and write $a = y(b)$ with $b \in B$.
3. The spacing around the vertical bar is wrong.  Either use `\mid`, or `\ |\`  (or just use a colon).

My version of that notation would be

$$ A = \{ a = y(b) \mid b \in B \}. $$

You could also move the specification of $a$ to the right-hand side and write

$$ A = \{ a \mid a = y(b), b \in B\}, $$

though I think that my preference would be for the former.

---

As noted in the comments, there are other common notations which would give the same set.  If $y$ is a function, then $A$ is the *image* of $B$ under $y$.  A very short notation for this is
$$ A = y(B). $$  You can also completely leave off the identity in the set-builder notation and write $A = \{ y(b) \mid b \in B\}$.

The choice of notation here is going to be largely up to your taste, and up to the taste of whatever reviewer is reading your work.  And remember that the goal is clarity of exposition—*good* notation explains what you are doing in a clear and precise way; *bad* notation causes confusion.  As long as you are not causing confusion, you're fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! I am leaning towards the second notation you suggested, i.e., with $a=y(b)$ in the right-hand side of the set builder.